# Show that $ \lim_{N \rightarrow \infty} \sum_{n=0}^N \gamma^n r_{n}$ for $\gamma < 1$ is bounded

Tags: limits

How can I show that:

> $ \lim_{N \rightarrow \infty} \sum_{n=0}^N \gamma^n r_{n} \text{, for } \gamma < 1$

is bounded if $r_n$ is bounded itself and $r_n \neq \gamma^{-n} * c$ for $c \in \mathbb{R}$?

It is obvious that $\gamma^n$ gets closer to zero and therefore this series has to be bounded. The problem is that e.g. $r_i$ is not known at this point so how can one show that in gerneral there *is* a limit?

Comment: That a limit when $N\to\infty$ is bounded is a statement I do not understand. A function is bounded, or not. A sequence is bounded, or not. A number is finite, or not. The limit of a sequence is a number.

Comment: @Did I added two conditions to $r_n$. Imho this should be enough to "*bound*" this series to some value since $\gamma^n$ is here a *discount factor* that will only add "almost zero" values to the sum for $N \rightarrow \infty$.

Comment: Adding the condition that $r_n\ne1/\gamma^n$ (but $r_n=2/\gamma^n$ is OK?) highlights the fact that you should think harder about the condition you added that $(r_n)$ is bounded. (And obviously you did not even read my first comment, did you?)

Comment: I think that he means "the limit exists and is finite" when he writes "is bounded".

Comment: @JohnHughes well yes, I guess this is what I mean. I see your point **Did**, I'll think about it how I have to condition $r_n$ but I basically want to show that "*there is a limit and it's finite*". :)

Comment: If $r_n$ is bounded, then restricting $-1 < \gamma < 1$ should be sufficient for $\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}\gamma^nr_n$ to converge.

Comment: Are the $r_i$ all supposed to be nonnegative? Or by bounded, do you mean that there's a number $M$ with $|r_i| < M$ for all $i$? (I'm guessing the former, because this sounds like "discounted rewards" from your use of "discount" and the letter "r", and rewards are usually positive.)

Comment: @Did $r_n \neq \gamma^{-n} * c$ for $c \in \mathbb{R}$. Would that make sense?

Comment: It would make sense, per se, and would be offtopic in the setting of this question.

Comment: @JohnHughes Well $r_n$ is a reward signal for an agent. This comes from an assignment I have to show for reinforcement learning. So the reward signal has to be chosen wisely.

Comment: OK...but if you want us to prove a theorem for you, it'd be nice to know what we may assume. May we assume the $r_i$ are nonnegative? (It's not necessary, but it makes the proof dead simple...)

Comment: You might want to take a look at Lakatos' book *Proofs and Refutations*; your sequence of edits to the claim you want us to prove falls in the category of activity that he refers to as "exception barring."

Comment: @JohnHughes I think it would make sense to allow also negative reward values. In terms of machine learning this would make sense but I don't know how much more complex such a proof would get. I don't think that I need a pure mathematical formal proof here. The question is "*what happens if you multiply each reward with a constant factor $d$ in a continuing markov process*". Therefore I want to show that the sum has a finite limit itself and from there it follows that multiplying each element with $d$ does not change that fact.

Comment: OK. Well, the more general proof's a little harder...but I've got to go do something else, so I'll leave it to others.

Comment: @JohnHughes I am amazed how exactly people look at such problems here. My script just says "*We see that future rewards are **discounted** by the factor $\gamma$ so their contribution dimnishes exponentially with the number of time steps. If $\gamma \lt 1$ and the rewards are bounded, the whole sum is bounded too.*" And that's it. ^^

Comment: "I don't think that I need a pure mathematical formal proof here" Sorry but the site is (mostly) about *pure mathematical formal proofs*.

Comment: @Did Nothing speaks against it. I said I don't need one, not that I won't accept one.

Comment: And now I've given one. I'll even go further: if you're writing programs, and hoping that they'll work, it's nice to have a *proof* that they'll do so. Perhaps the person who wrote your "script" thought it wasn't central to what s/he was teaching, but perhaps you should regard it as central to what you are *learning*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the $r_i$ are nonnegative and bounded by $M$, we have
$$
\sum_i r_i c^i \le \sum_i M c^i = M \sum_i c^i = M \frac{1}{1-c} < \infty
$$
Thus the partial sums $u_k = \sum_{i=0}^k r_i c^i$ form a bounded increasing sequence of reals, which always has a limit; that limit is the sum of the series.

(I've used $c$ instead of $\gamma$ here for convenience.)

I'm now enlarging to cover the case where the $r_i$ are not necessarily nonnegative, but there's a constant $M$ with $|r_i| < M$, and $0 \le c < 1$.

As before, let 
$$
u_k = \sum_{i=0}^k r_i c^i.
$$

Observe that for $n > m$, 
\begin{align}
|u_n - u_m| &= |\sum_{m+1}^n r_i c^i| \\
&= |c^m \sum_{m+1}^n r_i c^{ (i-m) }| \\
&= c^m |\sum_{m+1}^n r_i c^{ (i-m) }| \\
&<= c^m \sum_{m+1}^n |r_i| c^{i-m} \\
&<= c^m \sum_{m+1}^n M c^{i-m} \\
&<= M c^m \sum_{m+1}^n c^{i-m} \\
&= M c^m \frac{c^{n-m}}{1 - c} \\
&< M c^m \frac{1}{1-c}  
\end{align}

I'll show that the number $u_k$ form a [Cauchy sequence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_sequence), and hence have a limit. To do that, I need to show that for any $\epsilon > 0$, there's a number $K$ so large that for $n, m > K$, we have $|u_n - u_m| < \epsilon$. I'll show that this is true for numbers $n > m > K$, for if $n = m$, then the difference is zero, hence less than $\epsilon$, and if $m > n$, we can swap the labels and the proof remains valid.

So: assume given any number $\epsilon > 0$.  Pick 
$$
K = \frac{\ln\left(\frac{\epsilon (1-c)}{M}\right)}{\ln c}
$$. 
We can then see that 
\begin{align}
K\ln c &= \ln\left(\frac{\epsilon (1-c)}{M}\right)\\
\ln c^K &= \ln\left(\frac{\epsilon (1-c)}{M}\right)\\
c^K &= \frac{\epsilon (1-c)}{M}\\
\frac{M C^K}{1-c} &= \epsilon
\end{align}

Suppose that $n, m$ are numbers greater than $K$ with $n > m$. Then by the reasoning above, we have
\begin{align}
|u_n - u_m|  &< M c^m \frac{1}{1-c}  \\
&\le M c^K \frac{1}{1-c} \\
&= \epsilon, \text{ from the notes after the choice of $K$.}
\end{align}

Thus the sequence is Cauchy, and therefore approaches a (finite) limit. QED.

Comment: I've added the proof in the other case as well.

Comment: As a non-mathematician I'll have to think about this a little more but I'm confident that your proof is correct. Thank you for your answer!

Answer (score 1):

No. You need some condition on $r_n$.

For example, if $r_n=\frac{1}{\gamma^n}$, then the sum is unboundned.

Comment: Very good point. I'll add that condition since this does make sense in that particular topic despite the script only says that $r_n$ only has to be bounded too. It does not add your condition. Under the assumption that $r_n$ is conditioned, how could I show that the series is bound in general?

Comment: But if $0 < \gamma < 1$, then the sequence $r_n = \dfrac{1}{\gamma^n}$ is unbounded. So he only needs to add that $\gamma > 0$.

Comment: If $\gamma < 1$, then $r_n  = 1/\gamma^n$ is not a bounded sequence.